# How can I use armadillo library on windows 32 bit?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, armadillo

I'm using visual studio express 2013 and my windows 32 bit.
Under this enviroment, I want use armadillo lib. 
But in armadillo download site http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html, there is only for 64-bit(stable and old versions).
I'm a novice at computer programming.
Where can I find library for windows 32 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use Armadillo in 32 bit machine? Did you get any error or something? As far as I know Armadillo can be used with both 64 and 32 bits compilers. Indeed, I'm currently using last version of Armadillo (v6.5) with a 32 bits compiler. Please be more specific so we could help you.

If you are trying to compile the example that comes with Armadillo, it is only for 64 bits as it says in the readme file (section 8).

If you are getting some warning while compiling your own project, you could define `ARMA_32BIT_WORD` before including Armadillo to configure it to use 32 bits word instead of 64 bits.

```
...
#define ARMA_32BIT_WORD
#include <armadillo>
...
```

Comment: that alone will not work. OP is referring to precompiled bits in the download.